# How to center text, vertically and horizontally, in a circle?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to center text in my div which is in the shape of a circle, but it is not working. Vertical-align and align-text/content/items do not work. I have no idea what else to do. Also, does inserting the "figure" affect the alignment?

```css
.stats {
  width: 100%;  
  display: inline-flex;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: space-around;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.users{
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 315px;
    border-radius: 50%; 
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
   <div class="stats" >
            <div class="users ">
                <h2>Over <figure class="text-stat">#</figure> users and counting...</h2>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added flex and fixed some additional unused style, hope it helps!

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.stats {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.users {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 300px;
    width: 315px;
    border-radius: 50%; 
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="stats" >
    <div class="users">
        <h2>Over <figure class="text-stat">
            <span class="text-stat__number">#</span>
        </figure> users and counting...</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `display:flex;`

```
.users {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
.stats {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: space-around;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.users {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 315px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.stats {
  width: 100%;  
  display: inline-flex;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: space-around;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.stats {
  width: 100%;  
  display: inline-flex;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: space-around;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.users{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="stats">
  <div class="users ">
    <h2>Over
      <figure class="text-stat">#</figure> users and counting...</h2>
  </div>
```